# Supremum and infimum of $\{1 +(-1)^n/n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I am asked to find the supremum and infimum of the set
$$\left\{\left.1 +\frac{(-1)^n}n\;\right|\;n\in\Bbb N\right\}\subset\Bbb R.$$
What I first did was separated it in to cases and found that when $n$ is even, we get $1 +\frac{1^n}n$, and when $n$ is odd we get $1 -\frac{1^n}n$. I am lost from here. The book says the infimum is zero which I can understand I think, but I am not sure how they got $3/2$ as the supremum. All the help would be appreciated.

Note: I am learning to type math in to here so my apologies for not doing it for the set above.

Comment: Thanks @AnneBauval . I deleted my answer as I saw this is a duplicate.